# Should I use "this" or "next" in a question about time?

Tags: word-choice, this-next

My son asked me this question:

Today is June 12. Tom will play a video game on **_** Sunday (which is June 15).

And the choice is either "this" or "next."

So which one should it be?

Comment: This question has been asked for pretty much [every single day of the week](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/this-next?sort=votes&pageSize=50) now.

Comment: Sorry, people. I didn't know how to look for a related question like mine. Thank to all of you; again my apology.